# In useEffect about fetching api, how can i prevent the race condition

Tags: reactjs

I have a code where the url changes when the button is clicked, when i rapidly changing the url it loads but it shows the previous data before the current data. I'am trying to prevent the race condtion by setting the "setRunning" to false when it unmount on the useEffect

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { instance } from "../src/App";

export const useInstance = (url) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [error,setError] = useState(null);
    const [running, setRunning] = useState(true);
    const getData = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        setRunning(true);
        try {
            const response = await instance.get(url);
            if (running) {
                setData(response.data);
                setLoading(false);
            }
           
        } catch(error) {
            if (running) {
                setError(error.message);
                console.log(error.message);
                setLoading(false);
            }
          
        }
        
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
        return () => {
            setRunning(false);
        }
    }, [url]);

    return [data,error,loading]
};
```

I am expecting, when i instantly change the url by clicking the button, it wont show the previous data before the current data. But the above code is not working. How should i structure my code to prevent this?

Comment: I think what you need to do is that ideally you should prevent changing the url when a call is made. You can do so by disabling the button(that changes the url) until the loading is true

Answer (score 0):

you can set a **state in parent component (boolean) something like isSending** and whenever you are sending a request set isSending to true and when your **promise is settled** set isSending to false and check isSending in your useEffect before **calling getData**